# How to show that the Zermelo hierarchy is really a hierarchy?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-induction

In Cameron's *Sets, Logic and Categories* (p. 48-49), he sets out prove the following fact about the Zermelo hierarchy $V$, namely, that $V_\alpha\subseteq V_{s(\alpha)}$ for all ordinals $\alpha$. His proof proceeds by induction:

> *Case 1*: $\alpha=0$. Then $V_\alpha$ is the empty set, which is a subset of any set.
>
> *Case 2*: $\alpha=s(\gamma)$ for some $\gamma$. Take $x\in V_\alpha$. Then, $$x\subseteq V_\gamma\subseteq V_{s(\gamma)}=V_\alpha$$ so $x\in\mathcal{P}V_\alpha=V_{s(\alpha)}$.
>
> *Case 3*: [limit ordinal case...]

I'm quite confused by Case 2. It seems like Cameron is taking $V_\gamma\subseteq V_{s(\gamma)}$ as the (unstated) inductive assumption. But even then, if $x\in V_\alpha$, how do we know immediately that $x\subseteq V_\gamma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $V_\alpha=V_{s(\gamma)}$ is the power set of $V_\gamma$.  So, an element of $V_\alpha$ is the same thing as a subset of $V_\gamma$.